# passing variables into another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a windows app in c#. I have used three decimal variables: `counter`, `narrow`, and `broad` which store different values based on some calculations.

On clicking a button, a message box is displayed showing these three decimal values and then the application exits..

Now I want to add another form having three labels in which these variable values needs to be shown. Please explain, how can I pass those variables in the next form to display in individual labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Form...

```
public class CalculationResultForm : Form
{
    public CalculationResultForm(){}

    public decimal Counter
    {
        set { labelCounter.Text = value.ToString(); }
    }
    public decimal Broad
    {
        set { labelBroad.Text = value.ToString(); }
    }
    public decimal Narrow
    {
        set { labelNarrow.Text = value.ToString(); }
    }

    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This will close the form (same as clicking ok on the message box)
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Then within your existing form button click handler...

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalculationResultForm resultForm = new CalculationResultForm();
    resultForm.Counter = _counter;
    resultForm.Narrow = _narrow;
    resultForm.Broad = _broad;

    resultForm .ShowDialog();

    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: Why the `Application.Exit` call? Otherwise I like the answer, since it would also allow for the form to be displayed non-modally, enabling it to remain visible and continuously getting updated with new values through the properties.

Comment: The original question seems to imply that that is what happens currently - "On clicking a button, a message box is displayed displaying these three decimal values and the application exits" - Obviously it can be removed if not needed

Comment: thanx a ton! its the best answer as it worked well..instead of the ok button can i have a 'print' button which shows the print dialog box..actualy i want the user to print that scorecard directly...i m new in prog so pl help if there can be such commands to perform the action..
thanx!!

Answer (score 3):

One method is to create a new constructor in the 2nd form. THen you can use those values from the 2nd form.

```
public Form2(decimal x, decimal y, decimal z):this()
{
   this.TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(x);
   this.Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(y);
   etc...
};
```

From main form

```
Form2 frm2 = new  Form2(x,y,z);
frm2.Show();
```

Comment: I think you lose designer support when you do this though.

Comment: Ive never had issues with it.

Comment: I do this a lot too, the designer doesn't have a problem. Maybe if you hid the default constructor problems might occur, though.

Comment: You only have problems doing this if you don't also have the default constructor. That is the one Visual Studio calls when in design mode.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to probably add a new method, lets call it ShowWithDetails:

```
    public void ShowWithDetails(double Counter, double Narrow, double Broad)
    {
        CounterLabel.Text = Counter.ToString();
        NarrowLabel.Text = Narrow.ToString();
        BroadLabel.Text = Broad.ToString();

        ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use properties. The form you want to pass the values to is just another class.

add something like this to the second form:

```
public int counter {get; set;}
```

then from the first form you'd do something along the lines of

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.counter = 1;
form2.ShowDialog();
```

or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog post describing [how to do this without using ShowDialog()](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/pass-variables-between-form-windows-without-showdialog/).