# C# Multi Windows Form Selection

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a multi Windows Form project, where the value selected from the Combobox on one form should enable a ComboBox on another form.  Could anyone tell me how to do that?

On the Combobox on Form1, some of the items on the list are "Mango", "Banana", "Papaya", "Orange".

On the Combobox on Form2, the values are 1, 2, 3, 4.  So if a user select Mango or Papaya on Form 1, the combobox on form2 will be enabled for the user to select a number.  Otherwise, the combobox will remain disabled.

Here's what I do.

I created a public class with 2 properties for both forms.

```
public class FormValues
{
    private bool _secondcbb = false;
    private string _firstcbb = "";

    public bool SecondCbb
    {
        get
        {
            return _secondcbb;
        }
        set
        {
            _secondcbb = value;
        }
    }

    public string FirstCbb {get; set;}

}

// ..... On Form1:

Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
FormValue val = new FormValue();

private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(whatever inside)
{
    if(ComboBox1.SelectedText == "Mango")
    {
        val = true;
        frm2.ComboBox2 = val;
    }
}
```

I don't do anything on Form2.  Except adding the control and set the Combobox to be disabled.

Comment: One of about a thousand other questions related to... [passing variables into another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173973/passing-variables-into-another-form)

Comment: I was brand new to C# programming when I asked that questions.

Answer (score 1):

Make public static method on Form 2 that will change comboBox state if comboBox item on Form 1 is selected like this:

```
public static void ChangeState(bool state) // Method on Form 2
{
    comboBox2.Enabled = state;
}
```

Enable comboBox2 when item is selected:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(whatever inside)
{
    if(comboBox1.SelectedText == "Mango" || comboBox1.SelectedText == "Papaya")
        frm2.ChangeState(true);
    else
        frm2.ChangeState(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not setting the enabled property of the ComboBox2?
Like this:

```
frm2.ComboBox2.Enabled = true;
```

This way you also don't need the FormValue, or am I wrong?

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: I need a clearer example to answer this. (Code of Form1 and Form2 initialise/constructor)

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what your `FormValues` class is doing, but I don't think it's necessary in the first place.  In your `Form2` create a method which does what you need that form to do:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    // enable the control?
    // edit the control?
}
```

This would allow anything which holds a reference to an instance of `Form2` to manipulate it using the exposed functionality.  Provide such a reference to `Form1`.  Either it internally instantiates the instance of `Form2` or it requires one as a constructor argument.  Either way, `Form1` should have a reference to an instance of `Form2`:

```
private Form2 Form2Instance { get; set; }
```

Then in your control's handler in `Form1` you simply invoke the functionality on that instance:

```
this.Form2Instance.SomeMethod();
```